# Unable To Access Sandbox from Production Account

Tags: sandbox, access

I have a brand new Salesforce org and just created a few sandboxes for our dev team. However, none of them are able to login or reset the passwords to their sandboxes since they have never logged in. As the admin, I can see the sandboxes in production and there is a login option. However, when I click login on one of the boxes and get to the login screen that is pre-populated with my username, I enter the same password I use for production but still cannot login.  Even if I hit reset password on the login screen, I never get the reset password screen instead it just loops to resetting password.

What is the best way for me to access these sandboxes so that I can reset the user's passwords?

Comment: Does this helps you https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008y7bIAA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a selection in the template. Fixed that and I was good to go.